# (Selenium/Python) exec Issue

Tags: python, selenium

I've run into a small problem, basically, I'm trying to exec URL what is a variable. the variable is `driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")` this is my code

```
URL = driver.get(https://www.youtube.com)
```

but i keep this error in the output console when i try to exec URL

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MrCoInSanity\Desktop\python scripts\Youtube Bot\Youtube bot.py", line 66, in <module>
    exec URL
TypeError: exec: arg 1 must be a string, file, or code object
```

Anyways thanks for your time :)

Comment: Why are you using `exec`?

Comment: Please reformat your question for a better readability and add more code so other users can help you better. Also, read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.